# RegEx for extracting domains and subdomains

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to strip a bunch of websites down to their domain names i.e:

```
https://www.facebook.org/hello
```

becomes `facebook.org`.

I'm using the regex pattern finder:

```
(https?:\/\/)?([wW]{3}\.)?([\w]*.\w*)([\/\w]*)
```

This catches most cases but occasionally there will be websites such as:

```
http://www.xxxx.wordpress.com/hello
```

which I want to strip to `xxxx.wordpress.com`.

How can I identify those cases while still identifying all other normal entries?

Comment: Use [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to parse the URL components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You expression seems to be working perfectly fine and it outputs what you might want to. I only added an `i` flag and slightly modify it to:

```
(https?:\/\/)?([w]{3}\.)?(\w*.\w*)([\/\w]*)
```

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/S48FwF/1).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Python Code

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(https?:\/\/)?([w]{3}\.)?(\w*.\w*)([\/\w]*)"

test_str = ("https://www.facebook.org/hello\n"
    "http://www.xxxx.wordpress.com/hello\n"
    "http://www.xxxx.yyy.zzz.wordpress.com/hello")

subst = "\\3"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(https?:\/\/)?([w]{3}\.)?(\w*.\w*)([\/\w]*)/gmi;
const str = `https://www.facebook.org/hello
http://www.xxxx.wordpress.com/hello
http://www.xxxx.yyy.zzz.wordpress.com/hello`;
const subst = `$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Robert Harvey has suggested a useful method of `urllib.parse`, here's my attempt at the regex:

```
(?:http[s]?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^/\n\r\s]+\.[^/\n\r\s]+)(?:/)?(\w+)?
```

As seen at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fWgiHa/3)

## Explanation -

First, the regex checks whether there is a `https://` or `http://`. If so, it ignores it, but starts searching after that.

Then the regex checks for a `www.` - It's important to note that this has been kept optional, so if the user enters `my website is site.com`, `site.com` will be matched.

`[^/\n\r\s]+\.[^/\n\r\s]+` matches the actual url you need, so it won't have spaces or newlines. Oh, and there must be at least one period (`.`) in there.

Since your question looks like you want to match the sub directory as well, I've added `(\w+)?` at the end.

## TL;DR

Group 0 - Entire url

Group 1 - The domain name

Group 2 - The sub-directory

Answer (score 0):

```
print("-------------")

# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

    import re
    
    regex = r"(https?:\/\/)?([w]{3}\.)?(\w*.\w*)([\/\w]*)"
    regex1 = r"\.?(microsoft.com.*)"
    test_str = (
    "https://blog.microsoft.com/test.html\n"
    "https://www.blog.microsoft.com/test/test\n"
    "https://microsoft.com\n"
    "http://www.blog.xyz.abc.microsoft.com/test/test\n"
    "https://www.microsoft.com")
    
    subst = "\\3"
    if test_str:
        print (test_str)
    
    print ("-----")
    # You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
    result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
    if result:
        print (result)
    
    print ("-----")
    result = re.sub(regex1, "", result, 0, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
    if result:
        print (result)
    
    print ("-----")
```